# How to know when the PrimeNG scrollpanel is at the bottom?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using the PrimeNG ScrollPanel to show some text and I want the user to scroll to the bottom before a button is enabled for them to continue.

I've had a look at the docs but can't see a way of finding out what the current scroll position is and/or have an event when scrolled. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use scrollTop method. Example;

```
<p-scrollPanel #sc [style]="{width: '100%', height: '200px'}">
            <div style="padding:1em;line-height:1.5">
                The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding. His beloved
                son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. Through
                Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head
                of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect, but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands
                against the good of the family.
                The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding. His beloved
                son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. Through Michael's
                life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind
                and benevolent to those who give respect, but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the
                family.
            </div>
        </p-scrollPanel>
        <button (click)="sc.scrollTop(500)">Scroll bottom</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use virtualScroller instead, it doesn't have a scroll bar position detection but it has a property called lazy scrolling where you perform an action when the scroller hits the end.